# Play sound on Website on serverevent

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am writing a Twitchbot in Java. Currently I am trying to implement a function that launches a sound on a website. The webserver I am using in the bot is nanohttpd.

I can load css, js and other files from a normal webspace. But I dont know how to launch the sound on the website.

Until now i tried finding something but I only found Websockets and I really dont understand how i could implement it into nanohttpd.

So my question is: Do you have any Idea how this could work, or do you have some keywords I could google, or a better solution?

MFG XLS202